# knockout extenders not working concurrently

Tags: knockout.js

I have some extender code that I would like to be able to use concurrently. The issue is neither work once I try to extend Numeric with Range.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
            //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
            var result = ko.pureComputed({
                read: target,  //always return the original observables value
                write: function (newValue) {
                    var current = target(),
                        roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                        newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                        valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

                    //only write if it changed
                    if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                        target(valueToWrite);
                    } else {
                        //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                        if (newValue !== current) {
                            target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

            //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
            result(target());

            //return the new computed observable
            return result;
        };
```

Here is another extender...

```
  ko.extenders.range = function (target, intRange) {
        //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
        var result = ko.computed({
            read: target,  //always return the original observables value
            write: function (newValue) {
                alert(target());
                var current = target(),
                    newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseInt(+newValue, 10),
                    valueToWrite = newValueAsNum;

                if (newValueAsNum < intRange.min) {
                    valueToWrite = intRange.min;
                }

                if (newValueAsNum > intRange.max) {
                    valueToWrite = intRange.max;
                }
                //only write if it changed
                if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                    target(valueToWrite);
                } else {
                    //if the tested value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                    if (newValue !== current) {
                        target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

        //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
        result(target());

        //return the new computed observable
        return result;
    };
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xequence/0nL09w55/

Here is the offending implementation

```
var InitializePanelsApplicantViewModel = function() {
        this.CoverageLimit = ko.observable('').extend({required: true}).extend({numeric: 2}),
        this.CoverageLimitFailWhyCry = ko.observable('').extend({required: true}).extend({numeric: 2}).extend({range : 500}); 
        };         

        $(function (){
var masterVM = (function() { 
this.InitializePanelsApplicantViewModel = new InitializePanelsApplicantViewModel();
})(); 

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uoqdfyqs/1/) which I think shows the behaviour you want.

I've simplified the example a bit and made the following changes:

- The range extender is expecting an object with `min`
  and `max` properties. I changed this so that calls to `extend` pass objects rather than just a numeric value.
- The numeric extender is using `ko.pureComputed` not `ko.computed`. As the function has side effects I think you should use `ko.computed`. Please see the [knockout.js docs page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) for more on this.
- The range extender was using `parseInt` which overrides any rounding done in the numeric extender. Both now use `parseFloat`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I was using parseInt and not parseFloat. As for the pureComputed it was something too new for me at the moment and should have used your suggestion of ko.computed.